# Interview Questions that can be asked on TCP/IP, UDP, Socket Programming?

Tags: .net, sockets, tcp, udp

I am going for an interview day after tomorrow where i will be asked vaious questions related to TCP/IP and UDP.
As of now i have prepared theoritical knowledge about it. But now I am looking up for gaining some practicle knowledge related to how it works in a network. What all is going in vaious .NET classes.

I want to create a very small application like a chat or something that can make me all these concepts very much clear. Could you please suggest some questions related to TCP/IP that you generally ask or that you might have faced.

How communication is going from server to client. 
Right now I am studying TcpClient, TcpListener and UdpClient Class but I want to implement all of them so as to get aware about its working.

Is Chat application a Tcp/IP application ?

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where to start from?

- What is the essential difference between TCP and UDP?
- Which one uses a "handshake"? How many steps?
- Which one is considered "unreliable"?
- For which OS will TCP fit? Linux or Windows?

And for a bit more advanced questions:

- What is a TCP window stack? How does it affect it?
- What is a non-blocking operation?

..... very possible to learn, good luck!

Comment: @Thx Poni, from your questions I judge myself as I completed startup lessons as i can answer all of them now. For advanced questions I need to study up. Could you please suggest some application also. That will be a great help

Comment: I'd try to build a simple chat application. Check: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/ChatAsynchTCPSockets.aspx  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/TCPIPChat.aspx  . Generally, MSDN contains good examples to start with. For C#, check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx  .

Comment: Great questions, in addition, it's worth talking about some of the more common TCP issues in Berkly style sockets programming.